# How do I speed up this Where?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections, .net-3.5

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class ItemLimits
{
  public string strAccountNumber = string.Empty;
  public string strUserCode = string.Empty;
  public long lAccumulatedAmount = 0L;
}
```

I have an array of these with 50000 elements in it.

I also have a dataset of 50000 items (more or less), and I need to find the element in the `ItemLimits` array that matches to this dataset.

This is currently being done in a loop through the dataset with this:

```
ItemLimits ilItemLimit = itemlimits.Where(s => s.strUserCode.Equals(dataset[i].User_UserCode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                      && s.strAccountNumber.Equals(strUnEditedHomingAccountNo, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).First();
```

`strUnEditedHomingAccountNo` is fetched from the dataset earlier.

Once I've found the `ItemLimit` I need, I need to add to its `lAccumulatedAmount`.

What I've seen from my performance benchmarks is that this is very fast as the loop starts, but slows down over time. It's a linear slowdown which you can see in this graph I made:
[image: time per item in ms]

By the time I reach ~40000 items each item is taking ~40ms to complete. This makes sense in my head because I assume it's just iterating through the items one by one until it finds a match, which is obviously quite slow with large amounts of items.

The number of items in both the array and the dataset can vary greatly.

I've thought about trying to order the array and doing a `Array.BinarySearch`, but I don't know how to order it most efficiently given that the `strUserCode` and `strAccountNumber` can both change, and I can't predict the order of the dataset either.

This is the slowest part of the program which is why I would like to try optimize it (around 70% of the time is spent just doing this, and there's a lot of other stuff going on).

If anyone could give me some pointers on what I can do, it would be MUCH appreciated.

I'm using .NET 3.5 and I can't change that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oops. Is it possible to migrate questions across or should I delete this and go ask there?

Comment: I don't know, maybe a moderator can do that.

Comment: How about you start by storing the ItemLimits in a List and remove them from once you've linked it to the matching data record?

Comment: @Zache ItemLimits can be used more than once. They have to stay there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ditched the `Where` entirely and done it using the `Array.BinarySearch` using this comparer:

```
class ItemLimitsComparer : Comparer<ItemLimits>
  {
    public override int Compare(ItemLimits x, ItemLimits y)
    {
      if(Convert.ToInt32(x.strUserCode) < Convert.ToInt32(y.strUserCode))
      {
        return -1;
      }
      if(Convert.ToInt32(x.strUserCode) > Convert.ToInt32(y.strUserCode))
      {
        return 1;
      }
      if(Convert.ToInt32(x.strUserCode) == Convert.ToInt32(y.strUserCode))
      {
        if(Convert.ToInt64(x.strAccountNumber) < Convert.ToInt64(y.strAccountNumber))
        {
          return -1;
        }
        if(Convert.ToInt64(x.strAccountNumber) > Convert.ToInt64(y.strAccountNumber))
        {
          return 1;
        }
        if(Convert.ToInt64(x.strAccountNumber) == Convert.ToInt64(y.strAccountNumber))
        {
          return 0;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

(this is the first time I've used this, I suspect I have a bug lurking somewhere)

The `Where` has been replaced by this:

```
int index = Array.BinarySearch(itlaCreditLimits, new ItemLimits { strUserCode = dataset[i].User_UserCode, strAccountNumber = strUnEditedHomingAccountNo }, new ItemLimitsComparer());
if(index < 0)
{
  throw new Exception("Didn't find ItemLimit for UserCode = " + dataset.User_UserCode + " and account number " + strUnEditedHomingAccountNo);
}

ItemLimits ilItemLimit = itlaCreditLimits[index];
```

This has got me down from 15 minutes for all 50k items to 25 seconds.

Comment: If you first do the Convert calls and store the values in local variables you avoid some method calls, and I'd argue increase readability

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are correct to what's causing this problem and I suggest you use something with a fast look-up to speed things up. Something like a dictionary, it's very fast. You already know how to compare and see if you have the correct record and you also only look for one match, or the first...

Try something like this, you'll need to change the type of the DataSet (no idea of what you are using) and maybe decide how to handle key-collisions when making the `itemLimitDictionary` but other than that it should speed things up nicely:

```
public void DoTheNeedfull(ItemLimit[] itemLimits, DataSet dataSet)
{
    var itemLimitDictionary = itemLimits.ToDictionary(i => MakeKey(i.One, i.Two), i => i);

    for(var i = 0; i < dataSet.Count; i++)
    {
        var strUnEditedHomingAccountNo = BlackMagicMethod(dataSet[i]);
        var key = MakeKey(dataSet[i].User_UserCode, strUnEditedHomingAccountNo);

        if(itemLimitDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            // do your thing
        }
        else
        {
            // maybe this is an error
        }
    }
}

private string MakeKey(string keyPartOne, string keyPartTwo)
{
    return keyPartOne.ToUpperInvariant() + keyPartTwo.ToUpperInvariant();
}
```

Comment: I tried using a Dictionary (I should have mentioned that) but it didn't let me edit the `Value` part for some reason. Also lol @ BlackMagicMethod. I've actually found a way to do the Binary search and it's gone down from 15 minutes to 25 seconds on my machine using that.

Answer (score 0):

So as far as i understand you like to iterate through your dataset and than increase a *counter*. That *counter* is specific to some properties of the dataset entry.

So it sounds to be a job for the `GroupJoin()` linq statement. With that you would get an ItemLimits object with all matching dataset items as `IEnumerable<DataSetItem>`. Then you could call `Aggregate()` on this inner enumeration and write this information into the given `ItemLimits` object.